# Is 1 Thessalonians 4:17 the only verse that supports the rapture?

Tags: biblical-basis, rapture

Are there any verses in the Bible besides [1 Thessalonians 4:17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20thessalonians%204:17&version=NIV) that support the doctrine of the rapture?

Comment: This question assumes 1 Thessalonians 4:17 supports the rapture.

Comment: @BruceAlderman It absolutely supports the rapture...it's the main source for our knowledge of it. However, *what* you think that rapture is can vary drastically. One of the worst results of the popularization of dispensational eschatology is that everyone now thinks the "Rapture" somehow only refers to the concept of a "secret rapture". That there is a rapture is not under debate. It's definition is.

Answer (score 7):

There's also [Matthew 24:40-42](http://www.usccb.org/bible/mt/24:40)

> Two men will be out in the field; one will be taken, and one will be left. Two women will be grinding at the mill; one will be taken, and one will be left. Therefore, stay awake! For you do not know on which day your Lord will come.

and it's friend [Luke 17:34-35](http://www.usccb.org/bible/lk/17:34)

> I tell you, on that night there will be two people in one bed; one will be taken, the other left. And there will be two women grinding meal together; one will be taken, the other left.”

so long as you leave off the next verse

> They said to him in reply, “Where, Lord?” He said to them, “Where the body is, there also the vultures will gather.”

Which rapture folks might be likely to do.

It kind of leaves you thinking that the lucky one is the one who is left, not the one who was taken and eaten by a vulture. If this were pointing to a rapture, the one who was left would be the one eaten by a vulture.

Comment: Your last sentence has an error; I can't quite tell what you're trying to say

Comment: I don't really have an opinion on the rapture, but I view that last verse differently than some.  I see that [as an idiom](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13/meaning-of-where-there-is-a-dead-body-there-the-vultures-will-gather).  Still, +1 for the first two passages.

Comment: @JustinY Not only is there not an error in the last sentence, it's hysterically funny.

Comment: @Richard, yeah I should probably hold off on Bible interpretation, I'm not very well versed in it.  I only mentioned these passages because there in the NAB pretty much says SEE THESE FOR MORE INFO ABOUT THE RAPTURE in the footnotes, which I thought was a little odd coming from a tradition that rejects it.

Comment: I don't think these verses are talking about rapture, because given the context (of Noah and Lot) it seems to be referring to the wrath of God being poured out. Also, in most [translation](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2017:30&version=KJV) it says that day is on the day the Son of Man is revealed, which will not be until He returns.

Comment: @shredder just to be clear, that's what the New American Bible (Catholic Bible) says as well as the KJV.  Yeah, I was pretty much just making stuff up to coincide with the rapture (in the vein of Jenkins/Lehaye).

Comment: (or might be when He is revealed through the "two witnesses" .. just wanted to add that. God bless)

Answer (score 0):

Matthew 13:30 and the book of Joel. Search for the word harvest in the Bible. Many references to harvest in the Bible are referring to the separation of weeds and the wheat which represents the difference between the unsaved and the saved during the Lord's Day.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to find a difference in events that take place in 1 Thess. 4:17 and events that other scripture speaks of when referring to Christ's 2nd coming (as in Matt. 24) (if anyone can point any differences out, please do), so I'm not certain about that verse.

However, I think that this verse might:

> 34 But take heed to yourselves and be on your guard, lest your hearts be overburdened and depressed (weighed down) with the giddiness and headache and nausea of self-indulgence, drunkenness, and worldly worries and cares pertaining to [the business of] this life, and [lest] that day come upon you suddenly like a trap or a noose;
>   35 For it will come upon all who live upon the face of the entire earth.
>   36 Keep awake then and watch at all times [be discreet, attentive, and ready], praying that you may have the full strength and ability and be accounted worthy to escape all these things [taken together] that will take place, and to stand in the presence of the Son of Man.
>   [Luke 21:34-36](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%2021:34-36&version=AMP) (Amp)

Jesus tells us this after telling us about end-times 7 year tribulation events. I would say He could've meant to have the strength to escape the desolation of Jerusalem, but what He says to escape from is coming upon on the entire earth. Perhaps by strength, He means the strength to endure our sinful carnal urges (as in Rev. 3:10).

"[Be careful because that day will come upon you like a trap, for it will come upon the entire earth.]" We will/would be trapped with nowhere to escape to..except into His presence.

Another verse that might speak of rapture:

> Since you have kept my command to endure patiently, I will also keep you from the hour of trial that is going to come on the whole world to test the inhabitants of the earth.
>   [Revelation 3:10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=revelation%203:10&version=NIV)

Comment: See [my other comment on this usage of Luke](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7239/what-scripture-is-used-to-support-a-pre-tribulation-rapture#comment30459_11488), but that passage can hardly be used as support of a rapture. If such was a given, then it could fit, but nothing in it contradicts a no-rapture understanding of events either. In fact if anything, you have to stretch the normal usage of the concepts to make it fit.

Comment: It supports it well, but not full proof, as you said it doesn't exactly contradict a no-rapture belief. I had to remove my "almost certain" statement for that.

Comment: Ok, I really do think it supports it more than anything else, and I updated my answer with why. That's just my opinion atm.