# What is the biblical basis for a post-tribulation rapture?

Tags: biblical-basis, eschatology, rapture, premillennialism, tribulation

I am fairly well-versed in premillennial theology, however, I was challenged frequently while at Bible College on my point of view of a pre-tribulation rapture in favor of a post-tribulation rapture. I understand the principles of post-trib thought, but I fail to see any scriptural evidence for it. Can someone please point me to the scriptural evidence used to support a post-tribulation rapture?

I have read "Gospel of the Kingdom" by George Eldon Ladd and I enjoyed it, but I suppose that perhaps I did not properly understand it or his argument for a post-trib rapture.

Comment: I fail to see any scriptural evidence for any rapture... but good question nonetheless.

Comment: There is also the interesting "Post-Trib but Pre-Wrath" view. Which really isn't much different than Historic Premilennialism except they see endtime events playing out somewhat similarly to many Pre-Trib models just without a "Secret" Rapture and by distinguishing "Tribulation" for all and "Wrath" for the wicked. Just thought I'd mention it in case this (or another question) was what you were thinking and you just needed a name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What scripture is used to support a "Pre-Tribulation Rapture"?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7239/what-scripture-is-used-to-support-a-pre-tribulation-rapture)

Comment: @MattGutting This question asks for the biblical basis for the *post*-trib rapture, not pre-trib.  Or am I missing your point?

Comment: @Nathaniel Hm. There was a short mention of biblical support for "post-trib" in one of the answers to that question. As I re-read, though, probably not enough to give a decent answer to this question. I'll withdraw.

Answer (score 4):

**Revelation 1:9**

> I, John, both your brother and companion in the tribulation and
>   kingdom and patience of Jesus Christ, was on the island that is called
>   Patmos for the word of God and for the testimony of Jesus Christ.

The "great tribulation" is not a future event, it is an ongoing event. The Apostle John speaks of himself as enduring the tribulation of Jesus Christ during his lifetime. This tribulation will continue straight up until Jesus returns. His return marks the end of the tribulation, and the immediate beginning of eternity.

Many scriptures speak of the last trumpet, the seventh trumpet, or the great trumpet.

Matthew 24:31

> And He will send His angels with a great sound of a trumpet, and they
>   will gather together His elect from the four winds, from one end of
>   heaven to the other.

1 Corinthians 15:52

> in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trumpet. For the
>   trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised incorruptible, and we
>   shall be changed.

1 Thessalonians 4:16

> For the Lord Himself will descend from heaven with a shout, with the
>   voice of an archangel, and with the trumpet of God. And the dead in
>   Christ will rise first.

Revelation 11:15

> Then the seventh angel sounded: And there were loud voices in heaven,
>   saying, “The kingdoms of this world have become the kingdoms of our
>   Lord and of His Christ, and He shall reign forever and ever!”

My understanding of these scriptures is that they all describe the same event:

The Lord comes, raises the dead, and gathers the elect to bring them immediately to heaven. This is an apantesis, when a delegation leaves a city to escort in a dignitary and escorts that dignitary into the city. Examples in scripture are:

1. King David greeting the Ark of the Covenant when it was brought into his city
2. Jesus being greeted on Palm Sunday and escorted into Jerusalem.
3. Paul the Apostle being escorted into Rome for his visit.

Thus Jesus is leaving the heavenly city with a delegation of angels to welcome in his Church, only to quickly return to that heavenly city. It will not be secret, and when it happens, all wars will cease. There will be no more tribulation after Christ's appearance.

Answer (score 1):

I speak from a Seventh Day Adventist perspective.

The scriptures used to justify post-tribulation rapture are often the same scriptures used to justify pre-tribulation rapture. The main difference being -- we do not believe those who are Jewish will be treated any differently from other nations ([Gal 3:28-29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians+3%3A28-29&version=KJV)), and that all Christians make up what is referred to as 'Spiritual Israel'.

> But Jerusalem which is above is free, which is the mother of us all. (Gal 4:26)
>
> And as many as walk according to this rule, peace be on them, and mercy, and upon the Israel of God. (Gal 6:16)

With this in mind, then all scripture that refer to Israel in the last days refer actually to **all Christians**.

---

> Alas! for that day is great, so that none is like it: it is even the time of Jacob's trouble, but he shall be saved out of it. (Jer 30:7)

The time of Jacob's trouble is for all Christians. They "shall be saved out of it" because God will deliver them from those who persecute them, and they will not perish. The whole premise of Jacob's night of wrestling was that he suffered through the trial and was then saved from Esau by his faith. Likewise, Christians in the last days will suffer persecution ([Rev 13:17](https://www.google.ca/amp/s/www.biblegateway.com/passage/%3Fsearch%3DRevelation%2B13%253A17%26version%3DKJV%26interface%3Damp)), they will cry day and night to God for deliverance, and God will save them by their faith.

> And at that time shall Michael stand up, the great prince which standeth for the children of thy people: and there shall be a time of trouble, such as never was since there was a nation even to that same time: and at that time thy people shall be delivered, every one that shall be found written in the book (Dan 12:1).

Again, God's people, Christians, will be delivered. This is at the time of trouble and not before it. Christians in the last days are Daniel's people because there is no distinction now between Jews and Gentiles, only believers and non-believers.

> For then shall be great tribulation, such as was not since the beginning of the world to this time, no, nor ever shall be. And except those days should be shortened, there should no flesh be saved: but for the elect's sake those days shall be shortened. (Matt 24:21-22)

Elect refers to Christians not just converted Jews. (See also [Col 3:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Colossians%203:12&version=KJV)). The elect go through the great tribulation, but it is shortened for their sake.

---

The above, plus the lack of scriptures that depict two separate translation events or secret rapture, points strongly to Post-tribulation rapture.

Rapture, in this case, is simply the translation of living at Jesus' second coming, which is well backed by scripture. ([1 Cor 15:51-52](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2015:51-52), [Matt 24:31](https://www.google.ca/amp/s/www.biblegateway.com/passage/%3Fsearch%3DMatthew%2B24%253A31%26version%3DKJV%26interface%3Damp), [1 Thes 4:16-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Thessalonians+4:16-17))

The only difficult scripture is [Matt 24:40-42](https://www.google.ca/amp/s/www.biblegateway.com/passage/%3Fsearch%3DMatthew%2B24%253A40-42%26version%3DKJV%26interface%3Damp), which we interpret as figurative, since no one will be buying or selling in the last days who have victory over the mark of the beast ([Rev 20:4](https://www.google.ca/amp/s/www.biblegateway.com/passage/%3Fsearch%3DRevelation%2B20%253A4%26version%3DKJV%26interface%3Damp)), let alone working.

God's church will live through the great tribulation, but they will not be harmed by the plagues, and will be delivered.

> And not only so, but we glory in tribulations also: knowing that tribulation worketh patience; (Rom 5:3)

Answer (score 0):

This is my post tribulation rapture verses:

Rev. 21:9 - At the end of the Millennium

9 And there came unto me **one of the seven angels which had the seven vials full of the seven last plagues**, and talked with me, saying, Come hither, I will shew thee the **bride**, the Lamb's wife.

Rev. 16:15 - **The Sixth Vials Judgement**

15 **Behold, I come as a thief**. Blessed is he that watcheth, and keepeth his garments, lest he walk naked, and they see his shame.

YBIC,

eaglet

Comment: This answer would be improved by explaining how these verse fit with a post-tribulation rapture.

Answer (score -1):

Seal 1 - Preaching of the Gospel (Bow/Covenant) throughout the world from Ascension up to the end of the   Great Tribulation

Seal 2,3,4 - Wars and Rumors of Wars continued on; Economic Woes continued on; Death from Wars, Earthquakes, Famines, Calamities, and from Wild Beasts continued on from Ascension up to the end of the Great Tribulation

Seal 5 - Persecution and martyrdom continued on from Stephen and up to the last martyr to be killed in the Great Tribulation

Seal 6 - Great Tribulation, Bowls Judgement, Resurrection of the Dead in Christ and Rapture of the Alive in Christ, Second Advent

Seal 7 - The Millennium, the Thousand Years of Peace on Earth, the Half Hour Silence in Heaven

Trumpet Judgement happens at the end of the Millennium

White Throne Judgement happens at the Seventh Trumpet Judgement.

The Beast coming out of the bottomless pit; the time for judging the Dead; the Mystery of God shall be finished at the end of the Millennium

The Mystery of God is Christ.

God's plan of Salvation and Justice to mankind shall be made complete through His Son, Jesus Christ, at the White Throne Judgement, where death and sin will be destroyed, and all power, kingdom, and authority will be handed over to God, so that God will be all in all.

It is at the end of the Millennium where transgression will be finished, and sins will be put to an end, and reconciliation for iniquity will be made, and everlasting righteousness will be brought in, and the vision and prophecy will be unsealed, and the Most Holy will be anointed. Daniel 9:24

YBIC,

eaglet

Comment: When Jesus said in Matt. 28:20 I will be with you always even at the end of the age, it means until the end of time which is at the end of the millennium prior to eternity, the new heaven and new earth. The Day of the Lord is the Millennium. The Day of Christ is the Second Advent.

Comment: If what is in your comment is part of your answer, please move it into your answer since comments eventually go away.  Welcome to Christianity.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get a feel for how a Q&A site works.  Also, please take a look at [how we are different from other sites](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/24204)