How do believers in a pre-trib rapture reconcile this with belief in perspicuity of Scripture?
Those who believe in a pre-tribulation rapture often claim that it is clearly taught by the Scriptures, and the only possible interpretation for those who take the Bible at face value seriously. However, the arguments used to prove a pre-trib rapture are extremely complex and difficult for me to follow. Proponents generally acknowledge that no passage of Scripture teaches it plainly, but rather that it is an inference from a collage of different passages. Fair enough; I don't want to go into a full discussion of the arguments for/against here.
Rather, I was struck while reading Amillennialism and the Age to Come: A Premillennial Critique of the Two-Age Model by Matt Waymeyer by this argument he presents rebutting a particular amillennialist argument regarding the meanings of "first" and "second" within Rev.20:

The third difficulty with this argument relates to the perspicuity of Scripture. Simply stated, it is difficult to imagine that any interpreter would ever have taken this approach...prior to its discovery in the second half of the 20th century. How could even the most diligent of Bible students be expected to reach this conclusion? Why would the apostle John use such obscure language, demanding such a convoluted interpretive process?...As Harold Hoehner observes, "The complexity of this view makes it suspect."
(Amillennialism and the Age to Come page 221, emph. added)

(Note: this is not Waymeyer's argument against Amillennialism as a whole, nor any key part of it, but rather against a particular interpretation of the words "first" and "second" used in Rev. 20:5-6.) Waymeyer is himself a dispensationalist and a believer in a pre-trib rapture. But I cannot see how his argument here does not apply equally to the pre-trib rapture. I am wondering how he might respond to his own argument:

It is difficult to imagine anyone taking this approach prior to its discovery in the 1800s.

How could even the most diligent of Bible students be expected to reach this conclusion?

Why would Jesus and the apostles use such obscure language, demanding such a convoluted interpretive process?

The complexity of this view makes it suspect.


To be clear, I am not asking about the correctness of the pre-trib rapture. Rather, I am asking how do adherents reconcile this belief with the doctrine of perspicuity of Scripture, when it is the conclusion of an extremely complex reasoning process, and there is little-to-no evidence that anyone took this view prior to modern times.

Update in response to comments: The comments have suggested two possible reconciliations: either the perspicuity of Scripture is false or the pre-trib rapture theory is not an important enough issue for perspicuity to be relevant (as perspicuity properly only applies to central doctrines). Both of these would resolve the issue, but I do not think many who believe in a pre-trib rapture would take either option. Waymeyer certainly would not, as he uses perspicuity as an argument against a minute detail in the whole amillennialist argument, demonstrating both that he believes in perspicuity of Scripture and that he thinks it may be applied to issues not of central importance.

Good question.  Perhaps it is "perspicuity of Scripture" that is wrong. +1

Perhaps, but there are many who believe in both.

The perspicuity of scripture doesn't apply to everything, but only the central or essential doctrines of Christianity. Proponents of pre trib rapture may overstate their position, but that doesn't make it incompatible with perspicuity.

The issue which Waymeyer disputes on grounds of perspicuity is a much smaller detail, i.e. the possible typology of "first" and "second" in Rev.20

For clarification: when you say ' first and second within Rev.20', do you mean the first resurrection and the second resurrection? Or is this about some 'two-age model' in Waymeyer's book (i.e. a first age, and a second age)?

@Anne First resurrection and second death. The particulars of this amillennial argument are both not too clear to me and not really relevant to what I'm asking about, but I can add more details if that would be helpful.

Right, as per. ch.20 v.6. I am struggling to understand how the Q can be answered without recourse to flagging up some error(s) somewhere, but as you seek answers from believers in a pre-trib rapture - which I am not - this isn't a Q I can answer. So don't go into further details for my sake!

The argument that scripture would need to be obscure, convoluted and deliberately opaque if certain suppositions were true, is a valid argument, especially in the matter of the end times where wild and fanciful theories abound, which blatantly contradict the parables of Jesus and the apostolic doctrine.

Solution:   The rapture has not happened.  That is our hope because our citizenship is in Heaven.  The next thing to happen right now is Rapture. We are waiting for our blessed hope, the appearance of the glory of our great God, and the Savior Jesus Christ to transform our body to be like His glorious body.
The rapture will not be a secret.  The world will know that something big has happened because of the chaos and hazard the event will cause, and millions will not die but will be missing.  For example:
Matthew 24:40-41

Then two men will be in the field, one taken and one left, and two women will be grinding at the mill, one taken and one left.

Luke 17:34

I can tell you that tonight, there will be two beds in one. One will be taken, and the other left.

Paul and Silas traveled to preach the news about Jesus to the church in Thessalonica, a city in Macedonia, now Greece. Most of the Thessalonian Jews formed a mob to get rid of Paul.  The Thessalonian believers hid Paul until dark and sent him to Berea, another city in Greece.  While Paul was in Corinth, still in Greece, Paul was concerned about the church in Thessalonica, that the tempter had tempted them in some way, and that his labors among them had been in vain. Some people thought the Thessalonian church that the Lord had already come and that Judgment Day was upon them. Worse yet, these false teachers alleged that their message came from Paul.  So, they believed that it was useless to work because the end of the world was close at hand, thereby becoming a financial burden on the charitable Thessalonian church.  Apostle Paul realized the Thessalonian believers needed further teaching and wrote two letters. The first Thessalonian to encourage them and explain the day of the Lord more clearly.  The second Thessalonian explained why they should go back to work:
1 Thessalonian 2

Concerning the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ and our being gathered to him, we ask you, brothers and sisters, not to become easily unsettled or alarmed by the teaching allegedly from us, whether by a prophecy or by word of mouth or by letter asserting that the day of the Lord has already come. Don’t let anyone deceive you in any way, for that day will not come until the rebellion occurs and the man of lawlessness is revealed, the man doomed to destruction.

2 Thessalonians 3:6–15

In the name of the Lord Jesus Christ, we command you, brothers and sisters, to keep away from every believer who is idle, disruptive, and does not live according to the teaching you received from us.  For you know, we were not idle with you, nor did we eat anyone’s food without paying for it. We worked night and day so we would not be a burden to any of you. We did this not because we do not have the right to such help but to offer ourselves as a model for you to imitate. We gave you a rule that anyone unwilling to work shall not eat.  We hear that some of you are idle, disruptive, and busybody. We command and urge such people in the Lord Jesus Christ to settle down and earn the food they eat. Please take special note of anyone who does not obey our instructions in this letter. Do not associate with them, as they may feel ashamed.  Yet do not regard them as an enemy, but warn them as you would a fellow believer.

Now, we will address Prophet Daniel of what will happen  halfway into the tribulation.
Daniel 7:25 - He will speak against the Most High, oppress his holy people, and try to change the set times and the laws. The holy people will be delivered into his hands for a time, times, and half a time–1+2+0.5 = three and half years.
Daniel 12:11 - And from the time that the regular burnt offering is taken away and the abomination that makes desolate is set up, there shall be 1,290 days (three and half years).
Daniel 9:27 - He will confirm a covenant with many for one seven. In the middle of the seven, he will end sacrifice and offering. At the temple, he will set up an abomination that causes desolation until the end that is decreed is poured out on him.
These are Bible verses that Daniel mentioned, which is why some Christians believe we would be here for half the tribulation period. The bible lets us know some things will happen in the middle of tribulation, like the abomination that makes desolate.  But I do not believe we will be here, not even for a day of tribulation. Here are many reasons:
(1)  The Bible tells us to stay awake and be ready at all times because concerning that day and hour of the rapture, no one knows, not even the angels of Heaven, nor the Son, but the Father, only according to Matthew 24.  If we stay half the tribulation, then we will actually know the date that after three and half years into the tribulation, the trumpet to gather the elect will sound.
(2)  According to Luke, because no one knows the date and hour, it will happen like it did in these events:
Luke 17:26-37 - Just as it was in the days of Noah, so will it be in the days of the Son of Man. They ate, drank, married, and were given in marriage until the day when Noah entered the ark, and the flood came and destroyed them all. Likewise, just as it was in the days of Lot, they were eating and drinking, buying and selling, planting and building, but on the day when Lot went out from Sodom, fire, and sulfur rained from heaven and destroyed them all. So, will it be on the day when the Son of Man is revealed?
Let us take a close look at these two events, Noah and Lot:
Genesis 7: 13-20 - On that very day, Noah and his sons, Shem, Ham, and Japheth, and his wife and three sons' wives entered the ark. They had every animal, livestock, and bird of all its kind with them. As God had commanded, male and female of every living thing came with Noah. Then the Lord shut him in.  For forty days, floods kept coming to the earth.
Genesis 19:15 - When it was dawn, the angels urged Lot, saying, hurry! Take your wife and two daughters here and flee.  When Lot hesitated, the men grasped his hand and his wife and two daughters' hands and led them safely out of the city, for the Lord was merciful to them. As soon as they brought them out, the angel said, flee for your lives! Don’t look back, and don’t stop anywhere in the plain. But Lot said No, my Lords, here is a small town near enough let me flee to it to spare my life. The angel said, I will grant this request, too; I will not overthrow the town you speak of. But flee there quickly because I cannot do anything until you reach it.
(3)  The third reason why we will not spend a day in the tribulation is that the tribulation is going to be a difficult time as follows:
Matthew 24:21 - There will be great tribulation, such as has not been from the beginning of the world until now, and never will be.
Chapters 6 to 19 of the book of Revelation called the tribulation period a tumultuous time when God will unleash His full wrath on earth.  If that is the case, we will not spend a day of tribulation because we are no longer objects of God’s wrath according to these bible verses:
1 Thessalonian 5:9 - For God did not appoint us to suffer wrath but to receive salvation through our Lord Jesus Christ.  He died for us so that, whether we are awake or asleep, we may live together with him.
Romans 5:9 - Since his blood has now justified us, how much more shall we be saved from God’s wrath through him?
Romans 1:18 - God's wrath is revealed from heaven against all ungodliness and unrighteousness of men, who, by their unrighteousness, suppress the truth.
John 3:36 - Whoever believes in the Son has eternal life; whoever does not obey the Son shall not see life, but the wrath of God remains on him.
To supplement this solution, please visit my website: www.youtube.com/@wordin-spuire7772. Click on my video to see all the videos, then select a video titled “Rapture is Questioned.”

Hi thanks for your answer and welcome to Christianity.SE! I don't think that your answer has addressed the specific concerns that I brought up in the post, i.e. relating to the clarity of Scripture.

The pre-tribulation 'catching away' of 1 Thessalonians 4:17 is an event unique to the church, the body of Christ (Paul's gospel of God's grace and Christ crucified).
The "taken" of Luke 17:34-37 is specific to Israel and in regard to her final prophetic seven years which preceeds the receiving of her promised earthly kingdom of heaven for Christ's millennial reign. It is the period of time that they must "endure unto the end" (Matthew 24:13).
The church, the body of Christ, those required to have only faith in order to receive the free unmerited gift of salvation, the "ye" below, are not the "they" (below) of the tribulation.
1 Thessalonians 5:1-11

But of the times and the seasons, brethren, ye have no need that I write unto you.
2 For yourselves know perfectly that the day of the Lord so cometh as a thief in the night.
3 For when they shall say, Peace and safety; then sudden destruction cometh upon them, as travail upon a woman with child; and they shall not escape.
4 But ye, brethren, are not in darkness, that that day should overtake you as a thief.
5 Ye are all the children of light, and the children of the day: we are not of the night, nor of darkness.
6 Therefore let us not sleep, as do others; but let us watch and be sober.
7 For they that sleep sleep in the night; and they that be drunken are drunken in the night.
8 But let us, who are of the day, be sober, putting on the breastplate of faith and love; and for an helmet, the hope of salvation.
9 For God hath not appointed us to wrath, but to obtain salvation by our Lord Jesus Christ,
10 Who died for us, that, whether we wake or sleep, we should live together with him.
11 Wherefore comfort yourselves together, and edify one another, even as also ye do.

Recognizing Israel (God's earthly purpose) and the church, the body of Christ (God's heavenly purpose) as being two distinct groups 'in Christ' will greatly assist in seeing the perspicuity of scripture, which is an example of "rightly dividing" when studying (2 Timothy 2:15).
Ephesians 1:10

That in the dispensation of the fulness of times he might gather together in one all things in Christ, both which are in heaven, and which are on earth; even in him:

However, as both Peter and Paul point out, perspicuity is subjective to the reader:
2 Peter 3:15-16

And account that the longsuffering of our Lord is salvation; even as our beloved brother Paul also according to the wisdom given unto him hath written unto you;
16 As also in all his epistles, speaking in them of these things; in which are some things hard to be understood, which they that are unlearned and unstable wrest, as they do also the other scriptures, unto their own destruction.

1 Corinthians 2:12-16

Now we have received, not the spirit of the world, but the spirit which is of God; that we might know the things that are freely given to us of God.
13 Which things also we speak, not in the words which man's wisdom teacheth, but which the Holy Ghost teacheth; comparing spiritual things with spiritual.
14 But the natural man receiveth not the things of the Spirit of God: for they are foolishness unto him: neither can he know them, because they are spiritually discerned.
15 But he that is spiritual judgeth all things, yet he himself is judged of no man.
16 For who hath known the mind of the Lord, that he may instruct him? but we have the mind of Christ.


Hi, thank you for you answer, but this does not appear to address the concerns I asked about in the question. Perhaps you would be interested in answering this: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/96197/how-would-you-come-to-a-pre-tribulational-rapture-view-from-scratch ?

@DarkMalthorp Yes, thank you.  The notion came from here:  Galatians 1:11-12 "But I certify you, brethren, that the gospel which was preached of me is not after man.
12 For I neither received it of man, neither was I taught it, but by the revelation of Jesus Christ."  It was one of the "mysteries" that was revealed to Paul that was previously kept hidden:  Ephesians 3:9 "And to make all men see what is the fellowship of the mystery, which from the beginning of the world hath been hid in God, who created all things by Jesus Christ:"

Those "Taken" in Luke 17 are clearly taken in judgement.

@MikeBorden Indeed, so compared to the church, the body of Christ (with Christ being who was judged on our behalf), it is easy to see why they would be jealous of us.  Rom 11:11 "I say then, Have they stumbled that they should fall? God forbid: but rather through their fall salvation is come unto the Gentiles, for to provoke them to jealousy."  Rom 11:28 "As concerning the gospel, they are enemies for your sakes: but as touching the election, they are beloved for the father's sakes."
